# Scraping "Next pages" BeautifulSoup or Scrapy?

Tags: loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on my first real project. I am trying to scrape all nfl player news from [rotoworld's news feed](http://www.rotoworld.com/playernews/nfl/football/?rw=4&rw=1) :

I have been successful in pulling all the information I want off of the first page using bs4 from BeautifulSoup, but am looking into how to access information from the "older" tabs. I think it would be easy to do this if the url changed every time a new page opened up, but it doesn't. I was wondering if anyone has any tips for scraping "next pages" with BS, or if I should try an program like scrappy?

I am using python 3. Here is my code for those who are interested.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    my_url="http://www.rotoworld.com/playernews/nfl/football/"

    # opening up connection, grabing the page 
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    #grabs each news report

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"pb"})

    filename = "nfl_player_news.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    headers = "Player, Position, Team, Report, More Info, date\n"

    f.write("")

    for container in containers:
        ugly_player_info = container.div.div.text.strip("\r\n")
        neat_player_info = " ".join(ugly_player_info.split())
        player = container.div.div.a.text
        position = " ".join(neat_player_info.split()[3:4])
        team = " ".join(neat_player_info.split()[5:])

        report = container.p.text.strip()

        more_info = container.findAll("div",{"class":"impact"})
        info = more_info[0].text.strip()

        date_messy = container.findAll("div",{"class":"date"})
        date_time = date_messy[0].text.strip()
        ny_date= " ".join(date_time.split()[0:2])
        date = ny_date + " 2018"

        print("player" + player) 
        print("position" + position) 
        print("team" + team) 
        print("report" + report) 
        print("info" + info) 
        print("date" + date) 

        f.write(player + "," + position + "," + team + "," + report.replace(",", "|") + "," + info.replace(",","|") + "," + date + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, for such problems, you would like to look at one of two alternatives.

1. Using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to open the page and click on the "older" button each time and fetch the new page.
2. [Inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) the page and go to the network tab. Now click on the "older" button and you'll - in your case - a post call in the response to which the older page is returned as html. You can then parse it.

Also, you can use Scrapy to get a lot of this boilerplate code upfront and fasten your development.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am looking into scrapy right now. Having some issues as well though with the basic tutorial code haha :0.